# how to disable inherit in element style angular material default

Tags: angular5, angular-material2, angular-material-5

is there anybody know how to disable this in angular material default, i want to disable `font-size:inherit`. i have trying use Viewencapsulation.none but it doesn't works. Thank you

[image]

Comment: What version of Material are you on?

Comment: angular material 5 @p4r1